# Error while retrieving data from local storage

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

i am unable to retreive the data when i reopen my app.What should i do to permanently save the data
I tried this code:

```
<body ng-app="starter" ng-controller="Appctrl">
  <form data-ng-submit="addTodo()" class="todo-form">
    <input type="text" data-ng-model="todoText" placeholder="Enter new ToDo 
    item" />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Add Task" />
  </form>

  <ul class="unstyled">
    <li data-ng-repeat="item in todo track by $index">
      <input type="text">
      <span>{{ item.text }}</span>
    </li>
  </ul>

</body>
```

and in app.js:

```
.controller("Appctrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.addTodo = function() {
    $scope.text = $scope.todoText;
    $scope.todos = [];
    $scope.todo.push(text);
    $scope.todoText = ''; //clear the input after adding
    localStorage.setItem('todo', JSON.stringify($scope.todo));
    $scope.saved = localStorage.getItem('todo');
    localStorage.setItem('todo', JSON.stringify($scope.saved));
  };
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by _unable to retreive and show the value of the text_?

Comment: What errors are you receiving in the console? Did you verify that local storage is being set in your browser's developer tools?

Comment: The API should handle it. Whatever you enter you should post to a service and get it from there when you revisit your app

Comment: You cant store a array in localstorage and u seem to be declaring todos array while pushing todo array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case:

```
//you will need to parse the string to store it as an object
$scope.saved = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todo'));
```

You can use the following factory:

```
yourApp.factory('$localStorage', ['$window', function($window) {
        return {
            store: function(key, value) {
                $window.localStorage[key] = value;
            },
            get: function(key, defaultValue) {
                return $window.localStorage[key] || defaultValue;
            },
            storeObject: function(key, value) {
                $window.localStorage[key] = JSON.stringify(value);
            },
            getObject: function(key,defaultValue) {
                return JSON.parse($window.localStorage[key] || defaultValue);
            }
        }
    }]);
```

To use the factory you should inject it in your controller and use it like the following:

```
//to store
$localStorage.storeObject("sometoken", data);

//to retrieve
$localStorage.getObject("sometoken", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

When retrieving the data from local storage check for existence then `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todo'))` the get from local storage

Answer (score 0):

i solved my issue:

.controller("Appctrl",function($scope){

```
$scope.saved = localStorage.getItem('id');
$scope.id = JSON.parse($scope.saved);
localStorage.setItem('id', JSON.stringify($scope.id));


$scope.addTodo = function() {
//$scope.text=$scope.todoText;
$scope.id = [];
    $scope.id.push({text:$scope.idText});

    $scope.idText = ''; //clear the input after adding
    localStorage.setItem('id', JSON.stringify($scope.id));

};

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your code in controller.
You are doing : `$scope.todo.push(text);` instead of `$scope.todos.push(text);` itseems